# Swinging animation on image. (like a tavern sign.)

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

So I got this code here, but for some reason it will not work on my website. If there's something wrong with the code please tell me. It works in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rksh1tdv/) just fine.

HTML

```
<div class="swing" style="background-color:#transparent;">
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.swing {
-webkit-perspective:300px;
-moz-perspective: 300px;
-ms-perspective: 300px;
perspective: 300px;
}
.swing img {
-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
-moz-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
-ms-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
}
```

JS

```
$('.swing img').mouseenter(function(event)
{
var sign = event.currentTarget;
sign.rotationX = 0;
TweenMax.to(sign, 0.2, { rotationX:-20, ease:Power1.easeOut, onUpdate:onUpdate, onUpdateParams:["{self}"]});
TweenMax.to(sign, 0.4, { rotationX:8, ease:Power1.easeInOut, onUpdate:onUpdate, onUpdateParams:["{self}"], delay:0.2 });
TweenMax.to(sign, 3, { rotationX:0, ease:Elastic.easeOut, onUpdate:onUpdate, onUpdateParams:["{self}"], delay:0.6 });
});
function onUpdate(tween)
{
var target = tween.target;
target.style.webkitTransform = target.style.transform = target.style.msTransform = target.style.MozTransform = 'rotateX('+(target.rotationX)+'deg)';
}
```

Comment: Why won't it work on your website? Did you try turning it off and back on again?

Comment: Yea, I tried just about everything I could think of..

Comment: So adding this code makes your site display picture of putin riding bears?

Comment: ....Uhhhhhhh... It should be the Google Logo...?

Comment: The fiddle works. The code is pasted from the fiddle. All you have said is your site doesn't work. Maybe you could look in the console??

Comment: I think the problem is the JS file is not being detected. Any help?

Comment: Could you post your HTML code and point where you're embedding the JS code or if you have the JS script separate, show where the HTML code is calling the JS file?

Comment: Probably, you did not included `TweenMax.min.js` script

Comment: I've added an answer that is probably saying the same thing as your console's error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fiddle has an external resource. If you only copy/paste code from the code panels you will not include the resource.

Add this:

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.9.1/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
```